# Split action bar overflow icon gets covered by another icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I have an app in which the menu is growing a bit. A few of the menu items are dynamic, meaning they become visible depending on what you are doing. A few of the menu items are `showAsAction="always"` but the great majority are `ifRoom`. On my test device there is more than enough space for the `always` menu items however as menu items start becoming visible one of the icons will end up showing up on top of the 3 dots icon that opens the overflow menu, yet when this happens some of the menu items shown are `ifRoom` items. Is this normal behavior?  I've seen it on Android 4.0 and 4.4 so far.

EDIT: added screenshot, I should point the orange icon is normal but as you can see it is under the overflow menu icon.

[image]

Comment: Please post a screen shot

Comment: I added one now, I blanked out the rest of my icons to try to keep some privacy for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this post I think I was able to fix it 
[Split action bar - icons overlap when I use android:showAsAction="always"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743193/split-action-bar-icons-overlap-when-i-use-androidshowasaction-always)

Essentially you can't make the last menu item be a `showAsAction="always"` or it will have issues.